# jQuery Close DIV By Clicking Anywhere On Page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I would like to open `email-signup` when I click on `email-signup-link`.  Then I would like to close it by clicking anywhere on the page except for the box itself, of course.

I have looked around on this site and there are various solutions for this problem but every one I've tried shows and then hides my div instantly.  I must be doing something wrong.

This is the HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="email-signup-link">Sign Up</a>
<div id="email-signup">
    <div id="inner">
        <h2>E-mail Notifications</h2>
        <input class="" type="text" name="description" placeholder="Enter your e-mail address" id="description" />
        <a href="#">Sign Up</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my Javascript:

```
$('#email-signup').click(function(){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$("#email-signup-link").click(function() {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#email-signup').show();
});
$(document).click(function() {
    $('#email-signup').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two things.  You don't actually have `e` defined, so you can't use it.  And you need `stopPropagation` in your other click handler as well:

```
$('#email-signup').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$("#email-signup-link").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#email-signup').show();
});
$(document).click(function() {
    $('#email-signup').hide();
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Nczpb/

Comment: Just heads up  ```e.stopPropagation();``` can sometimes cause unwanted events. so say if you click off ```#email-signup``` with the intention of clicking submit  ```e.stopPropagation();``` will prevent your form from submitting.

Comment: @codenamejames If you click off of `#email-signup` then there is no `stopPropagation` at all so you'll be fine.  `stopPropagation` only stops the event from bubbling up the DOM.  Unless your submit button is somehow a parent of `#email-signup` your example will never be a problem.

Answer (score 8):

```
$(document).click (function (e) {
    if (e.target != $('#email-signup')[0]) {
        $('#email-signup').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can someone explain what role the `[0]` plays in this solution please? @Alexander ? Thanks

Comment: The jQuery selector (`$()`) always returns an array. The [0] simply selects the first element of this array. If ID's are used correctly this should be the only result.

Answer (score 1):

The way I've often seen this done is by overlaying the page behind the form with a div (greyed out usually). With that, you could use:

```
$("#greydiv")..click(function() {
    $("#email-signup").hide();
    $("#greydiv").hide();
});
```

...or something simliar.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(":not(#email-signup)").click(function() {
     $("#email-signup").hide();
});
```

Although you'd be better off having some kind of an overlay behind the popup and binding the above click event to that only.

Comment: Please make that $(':not(#email-signup)') if you're going to do it this way.

Comment: Why? The .not() method will end up providing you with more readable selections than pushing complex selectors or variables into a :not() selector filter. In most cases, it is a better choice.

Comment: Also, -1 for potentially adding thousands of event listeners if there's a lot of tags on the page.

Comment: Because you first select all the tags and then make another function call, how is `$(:not(#id))` less readable than `$("*").not('#id')`? That's like selecting all entries in a database and manually filtering instead of letting the database select only what you need.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/jquery-css3-not-vs-not looks like there is enough of a difference between the two for it to matter. thanks

Comment: Mikey G: I deleted my answer, but I think your message of an "overlay" is less descriptive than specifying how to create that overlay with a wrapping element.

Answer (score 0):

```
var mouse_is_inside = false;

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.form_content').hover(function(){ 
        mouse_is_inside=true; 
    }, function(){ 
        mouse_is_inside=false; 
    });

    $("body").mouseup(function(){ 
        if(! mouse_is_inside) $('.form_wrapper').hide();
    });
});
```

as referenced in another stackoverflow post...